# Удаление пустых словарей при использовании фильтра в json

Tags: python, json, list, объекты, filter

Паршу json данные, мне нужны только те объекты в списке, айди которых совпадает с заданными мною. Но проблема в том что у меня на месте пропусков создаются пустые словари. Скриншоты ниже. Что можно сделать? Буду признателен за ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# Открытие вышесозданного файла и чтение информации
with open('products_first_unsorted.json', encoding='utf-8') as products_json_file:
    json_file = json.load(products_json_file)
    for index, value in enumerate(products_ids, start=0):
        filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['category'] == value, json_file))

        # Запись сортированных данных в отдельный файл
        with open('products_second_unsorted.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as products_json_file:
            json.dump(filtered_list, products_json_file, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал тот же метод filter() в виде filter(None, Имя массива)), вот только теперь у меня две квадратные скобки до списка и после, ибо приходится переносить во временный массив данные чтоб потом использовать это.